# dotNet Core Clear Dropdownlist selections

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, dropdown, unselect

I have a Razor View with a dropdown list:

`<select size="7" style=" width: 275px; color:#967a42;" class="table-dark" asp-for="OptionsToAdd" asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.OptionsDD, "Value", "Text"))" multiple></select>`

When I submit the page, the controller resets the list and selected items, yet when the view is displayed, the same items are still selected from before the POST. How can I clear this?

This only happens in the view. The model that is passed in has all items in the Viewbag.OptionsDD with selected=false.

Comment: Can you share your model data you send to the view and the action code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to change you code like below:

```
  <select size="7" style=" width: 275px; color:#967a42;" class="table-dark" name="OptionsToAdd"  asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.OptionsDD, "Value", "Text"))" multiple> 
    </select>
```